# Javascript check box checked for specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I want to know is that how to check those boxes only which trues my if condition right now all the check boxes are getting checked.... please help....

```
for ( var t = 0; t < contactsJsonArray.length; t++) {
    for ( var j = 0; j < optionresponse.length; j++) {
        if (optionresponse[j].contactid == contactsJsonArray[t].id) {
            $(".checkHit").each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $(this).attr('checked','checked');

Comment: Please post the HTML. `.checkHit` will match all the checkboxes, what you want to do is identify the checkbox for a specific `contactid`

Comment: @Dementic—`this.checked = true` is a very much more efficient way to write `$(this).attr('checked','checked')` and is more likely to actually check the checkbox. Setting the attribute only sets whether the checkbox is checked **by default** and if the user has already interacted with the checkbox, setting the attribute will not change its checkedness (in browsers consistent with HTML5).

Comment: pls provide http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Dont use each loop for .checkHit because u have a same class to all the check boxes instead for each just use the index as shown below

```
please remove /*$(".checkHit").each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
            }); */

use the below line this will chekck single check box
$($('.checkHit')[j]).attr('checked','checked');
```

i hope this might help you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help....You are awesome
Now there is only one problem.
That [j] are checked fine
but whenever i am clicking on any check box then the [j]'s checks disappears immediately
how to hold them on screen..